# Add category information beneath post?

Tags: posts, categories

I was wondering if it's possible to automatically show some text about a given category beneath the post. I'd like to be able to show some text beneath some (but not all) categories.

**Use case:**
I'm using affiliate-links and want to make it clear for the visitors that I may receive commission on some links in a post. As a result I've created a category called "affiliate" and would like to show some information about what affiliate means. Instead of just copy/pasting the same description to the bottom of every post with affiliate links, I'd like a way to iterate the description at a later date and would therefore prefer a solution that shows the text based on the category.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use the [`category_description`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/category_description) for that.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be a simple filter on `the_content`:

```
function my_affiliates_descr($content) {
 if (is_single() && has_category('affiliate')) {
  $content .= 'This is an affiliate post';
 }
 return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content','my_affiliates_descr');
```

You could combine that with `category_description()` as suggested in a comment to the question to get:

```
function my_affiliates_descr($content) {
 if (is_single() && has_category('affiliate')) {
  $content .= category_description( get_category_by_slug('affiliate')->term_id );;
 }
 return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content','my_affiliates_descr');
```